# How to find fundamental matrix based on other fundamental matrix and camera movement?

Tags: computer-vision, stereo-vision, optimization

I am trying to speed up some multi-camera system that relies on calculation of fundamental matrices between each camera pair.

Please notice the following is pseudocode. `@` means matrix multiplication, `|` means concatenation.

I have code to calculate `F` for each pair `calculate_f(camera_matrix1_3x4, camera_matrix1_3x4)`, and the naiive solution is

```
for c1 in cameras:
    for c2 in cameras:
        if c1 != c2:
            f = calculate_f(c1.proj_matrix, c2.proj_matrix)
```

This is slow, and I would like to speed it up. I have ~5000 cameras.

---

I have pre calculated all rotations and translations  (in world coordinates) between every pair of cameras, and internal parameters `k`, such that  for each camera `c`, it holds that `c.matrix = c.k @ (c.rot | c.t)`

Can I use the parameters `r, t` to help speed up following calculations for `F`?

---

In mathematical form, for 3 different cameras `c1`, `c2`, `c3` I have

`f12=(c1.proj_matrix, c2.proj_matrix)`, and I want `f23=(c2.proj_matrix, c3.proj_matrix)`, `f13=(c1.proj_matrix, c3.proj_matrix)` with some function `f23, f13 = fast_f(f12, c1.r, c1.t, c2.r, c2.t, c3.r, c3.t)`?

---

A working function for calculating the fundamental matrix in numpy:

````
def fundamental_3x3_from_projections(p_left_3x4: np.array, p_right__3x4: np.array) -> np.array:
    # The following is based on OpenCv-contrib's c++ implementation.
    # see https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/sfm/src/fundamental.cpp#L109
    # see https://sourishghosh.com/2016/fundamental-matrix-from-camera-matrices/
    # see https://answers.opencv.org/question/131017/how-do-i-compute-the-fundamental-matrix-from-2-projection-matrices/
    f_3x3 = np.zeros((3, 3))
    p1, p2 = p_left_3x4, p_right__3x4

    x = np.empty((3, 2, 4), dtype=np.float)
    x[0, :, :] = np.vstack([p1[1, :], p1[2, :]])
    x[1, :, :] = np.vstack([p1[2, :], p1[0, :]])
    x[2, :, :] = np.vstack([p1[0, :], p1[1, :]])

    y = np.empty((3, 2, 4), dtype=np.float)
    y[0, :, :] = np.vstack([p2[1, :], p2[2, :]])
    y[1, :, :] = np.vstack([p2[2, :], p2[0, :]])
    y[2, :, :] = np.vstack([p2[0, :], p2[1, :]])

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            xy = np.vstack([x[j, :], y[i, :]])
            f_3x3[i, j] = np.linalg.det(xy)

    return f_3x3
```
````

Comment: The function you use is the same I used [here](https://github.com/decadenza/SimpleStereo/blob/master/simplestereo/calibration.py#L1010). However, giving the interdependence of the element of the camera matrix , I don't think you can speed up the process. Also, whatever the number of cameras, it makes little sense: you can calculate the fundamental matrices once per camera pair and store them!

Comment: I asked this on SO as well, there is a [numba answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70549938/how-to-find-fundamental-matrix-based-on-other-fundamental-matrix-and-camera-move) there. I ended up vectorizing for two vectors of cameras, yielding a matrix of fundamental matrices. The speedup was X1000